# How to import referenced files (XML ) in AWS Glue script

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to run glue job in FAIR Scheduling mode . For this I created  one xml file with name fairschedular.xml

Then I added this fairschedular.xml in s3 bucket and add that location in reference path of glue job  as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
 <pool name="1">
   <schedulingMode>FIFO</schedulingMode>
   <weight>1</weight>
   <minShare>2</minShare>
 </pool>
 <pool name="2">
   <schedulingMode>FIFO</schedulingMode>
   <weight>1</weight>
   <minShare>2</minShare>
 </pool>
</allocations>
```

[image]

Then I used in script as follows :

```
class JobBase(object):
    
    fair_scheduler_config_file= "fairscheduler.xml"
    rowAsDict={}
    Oracle_Username=None
    Oracle_Password=None
    Oracle_jdbc_url=None

    def __start_spark_glue_context(self):
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName("python_thread").set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR').set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", self.fair_scheduler_config_file)
        self.sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        self.glueContext = GlueContext(self.sc)
        self.spark = self.glueContext.spark_session
```

But when code is running I don't see fair schedule  pools in spark ui history server . I do see FAIR scheduling.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues is resolved . I can see in AWS logs pool are getting generated.